# Image error once uploading an image file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine

Upload an image to Google Cloud Store but once deploying it to Google Cloud, an following error:
       *- Error: Server Error
       - The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
       -Please try again in 30 seconds.*
Thanks help from you.

```
public class UploadfilesServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public static final String BUCKETNAME = "bucket_endpoints";
        public static final String FILENAME = "test.jpg";
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException {
            URL res = getClass().getResource("transform_before.jpg");
            File file = new File(res.getFile());
            //Create bFile with byte array
            byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
            //convert file into array of bytes
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();


            FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
            GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
               .setBucket(BUCKETNAME)
               .setKey(FILENAME)
               .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
               .setAcl("public-read")
               .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value");
            AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());
             boolean lock = true;
             FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock);
             writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock);

             writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bFile));


             // Now finalize
             writeChannel.closeFinally();
             resp.getWriter().println("Done writing...");

        }
    }
```

Comment: First, there should be an error in the logs - post it here. Second, the `FIleService` is deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you recommend me which one will be replaced FileService ?

Comment: Cloud Storage is the replacement: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/